# HTML / JS: Enable disable textbox when one of two radio button checked

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

regarding my question above, I have two radio button, radio button 1 have dropdown list, radio button 2 have textbox. If radio button 1 checked, the dropdownlist will enabled and the textbox will be disabled. Same goes when choose radio button 2, the textbox will enable and the dropdown will disabled.
Below is the photo:

[image]

Below is my code:

record.php

```
<?php

    $smt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ets_team WHERE status = 1 AND (team_id != 1 AND team_id !=2) ORDER BY team_name ASC");
    $smt->execute();
    $results = $smt->fetchAll();

?>   

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="radio">
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked="">
        Team:
        </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" name = "team_id">
            <option value="">Please select...</option>
            <?php foreach ($results as $row2): ?>
            <option value= <?php echo $row2["team_id"]; ?>><?php echo strtoupper($row2["team_name"]); ?></option>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="radio">
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked="">
        Tools:
        </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tools_name" required>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me to solve this? Many thanks.

Comment: For starters, you HTML is invalid. IDs must be unique — your radio buttons both have the same ID.  Also, they have the same value, which makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

Onclick of radio button you can check the value of radio button and depending upon that either add `prop(disabled,true)` or `prop(disabled,false)` to your html element

**Demo Code** :

```js
$("input:radio").click(function() {
//getting option clicked value
    if($(this).val() == "option1") {
      //set select box enable
      $("#exampleSelect1").prop('disabled', false);
      //disable textbox
      $("input[name=tools_name]").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $("#exampleSelect1").prop('disabled', true);
      $("input[name=tools_name]").prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="radio">
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1"checked="" >
        Team:
        </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" name = "team_id">
            <option value="">Please select...</option>
            <?php foreach ($results as $row2): ?>
            <option value= <?php echo $row2["team_id"]; ?>><?php echo strtoupper($row2["team_name"]); ?></option>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="radio">
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option2" >
        Tools:
        </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tools_name" required disabled>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```